# How to get an instance of a controller in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm trying to access an instance of a controller that has been wired automatically using App.initialize();

I've tried the below but it returns a Class not an instance.

`Ember.get('App.router.invitesController')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer works with RC1/RC2.

Now you can use the `needs` declaration in order to make the desired controller accessible. Here's an example:

Suppose I want to get something from my `SettingsController` from within my `ApplicationController`. I can do the following:

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isPublic: true
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'settings',
  isPublicBinding: 'controllers.settings.isPublic'
});
```

Now in the context of my `ApplicationController`, I can just do `this.get('isPublic')`

Comment: I got this to work using the latest EmberJS by using `needs: ['settings']`.

Answer (score 19):

I have a quick post about this exact subject on my Blog. It's a little big of a different method, but seems to work well for Ember.js RC1.

Check it out at: http://emersonlackey.com/article/emberjs-instance-of-controller-and-views

The basic idea is to do something like:

```
var myController = window.App.__container__.lookup('controller:Posts');
```

Comment: Yehuda has interesting comments about this.  He actually changed __container__ from just container because he didn't want people using this "private" api.  I need to access a controller from my main App application and see no alternative to this.  Actually, looking through discourse's source code, they are doing something like this also. Discourse.__container__.lookup('controller:modal').get('currentView'); (Discourse was created by Steve Atwood he created Stack Overflow, so it seems that it is the only alternative right now.

Comment: It... wokrs, thanks you. But seriousely, we have nothing less crappy ?to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can access a controller instance inside an action in the router via `router.get('invitesController')`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Pk4k2/:

```
App.InvitesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
                var invitesController = router.get('invitesController');
            },
            anAction: function(router) {
                var invitesController = router.get('invitesController');
            }
        })
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any controller instance by name using [lookup method of Application instance](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/ApplicationInstance/methods/lookup?anchor=lookup).
To get Application instance you can use [getOwner](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fapplication/getOwner) from any route or controller.

```js
const controllerName = 'invites';
Ember.getOwner(this).lookup(`controller:${controllerName}`));
```

*Works for me in Ember 2.4 - 3.4.*